# VS CODE, emmet срабатывает через раз. Что бы точно сработал нужно через меню правка?

Tags: visual-studio-code

то есть tab не всегда отрабатывает, поему не могу понять.

Comment: Думаю у вас что-то там ещё установлено по emmet

Comment: да, но я удали эмет лайв